# can't change style all elements with javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't change the width of element with classname `range`. First element has 70% width, next elements will have 70% width instead of 0. I must add so the same number display correctly in circle near bar

```
function zero(){
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        bars[i].style.width=number + "%";
        inners[i].innerHTML=number + "%";
        console.log(i);
    }

}
```

https://codepen.io/Katharsis/pen/rKxZbe

Comment: Please share a **runnable** [mcve] with us, [here's how to make one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/6634591).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to every .range2 .range3 .range4 ... in css

```css
height: 100%;
background-color: #1cea42;
```